# The best workbook of Discrete Math

Tags: discrete-mathematics, book-recommendation

Could you please suggest the best(in your opinion) workbook to study the Discrete Math?
Thanks.

Comment: In my opinion, definitetly the best is *"Concrete Mathematics: a foundation for computer science" R. L. Graham - D.E. Knuth - O. Patshnik* , either because it covers a wide range of arguments, and because it has a number of well chosen exercises with answers, but specially because its starting section is unvaluably clear and precise in addressing the student to acquire the right mental habits and tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graham, Knuth, Patashnik, Concrete mathematics

Ross, Wright, Discrete mathematics

I do prefer the 1st one, however it does not cover the whole discrete maths. So, the widder book seems to be the second one.

Comment: Thanks really good books, and one more I found Rosen also very useful